# Entity Framework use datepart function on column to get month or day or year part

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a sql statement

Say for example

'''Select id, datepart(MONTH, dateof) from table name'''

I want to do use datepart in Entity Framework. Ie I have a column that is a full date but want to use linq query to take only part of that date. I have seen a lot of examples that Don't seem to work on an existing column.

Version 8.0

```
var data = (from p in 
context.datatable 
join s in context.data2 on 
p.id equals s.id into ij from res in 
ij.DefaultIfEmpty() 
Select new { p.id, p.name, 
sqlfunctionextentions.(Datepart)
```

should be here but it isn't

Any advice appreciated

Comment: What does not work? Show your attempts. Which EF Version?

Comment: Version 8.0   var data = (from p in context.datatable join s in context.data2 on p.id equals s.id into ij from res in ij.DefaultIfEmpty() Select new { p.id, p.name, sqlfunctionextentions. (Datepart) should be here but it isn't

Comment: Include additional details in question.

Comment: Use just `dateTime.Month`

Comment: what do you mean by Datepart?

Comment: Where did `sqlfunctionextensions` come from?

Comment: That doesn't work @SvyatoslavDanyliv, it is mapped as a date time variable in the model. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is not translated? Which Database do you use?

Comment: SQL Server has this mapping [Date and time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions). Maybe you are mixing EF Core with old EntityFramework?

Comment: Date.value.month I think works. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction :)